# how do I prove that $1 > 0$ in an ordered field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've started studying calculus. 
As part of studies I've encountered a question.
How does one prove that $1 > 0$?

I tried proving it by contradiction by saying that $1 < 0$,
but I can't seem to contradict this hypothesis.

Any help will be welcomed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If $1<0$ then  $-1>0$, hence $1=(-1)\cdot(-1)>0$.

Comment: Why do you assume that (−1)⋅(−1)>0 ?

Comment: He doesn't assume it. The product of positives is positive. That's part of the definition of an ordered field.

Comment: I do not assume that. I assume that $1<0$. By adding $-1$ on both sides, I find $0<-1$. By multiplying with the positive(!) number $-1$ then $1>0$ follows.

Comment: product of positives is positive - What is the name of this characteristic of the ordered field? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know if it's called anything, but the definition goes like this: An ordered pair $(F,P)$ where $F$ is a field and $P \subset F$ satisfies (1) $0 \in P$ and (2) $x,y \in P \implies x+y \in P$ and $xy \in P$ is said to be an *ordered field* and $P$ is said to be the *positive cone of $F$*. $\quad$ It's an easy exercise to prove that if $(F,P)$ is an ordered field then $x \leq y \iff y-x \in P$ defines a total order on $F$.

Comment: @kahen thanks for bear with me.

Comment: Oh. I forgot part of the definition. You need (3) $F$ is the disjoint union of $P\setminus\{0\}$, $-P\setminus\{0\}$ and $\{0\}$. Otherwise $P$ is just a prepositive cone.

Comment: Please tell me if I'm wrong but IMO the answer is a [circumlocution](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/de/worterbuch/englisch/circumlocution): $1=1\cdot 1>0$ - done.

Comment: @Filippo: yes square of a non-zero member of an ordered field is positive.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you for the confirmation.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the trivial inequality $x^2 > 0$ for all $x\neq 0$. Prove this fact and use it to prove $1 >0$.

Comment: If you use this, you also have to prove that $1\neq 0$. It's ok, but the prove is incomplete by a trifle.

Answer (score 10):

Let’s consider the question in the ordered field of real numbers.
By the trichotomy axiom of inequality, only one of the following is true:
$$ 1=0 $$
$$ 1<0 $$
$$ 1>0 $$
Now, by the nontriviality axiom of the real numbers, $ 1\ne 0 $, so we’ve ruled out the first possibility.

Now suppose $ 1<0 $. Then for $ a\in R $, $ a>0 $, by the multiplication axioms of an ordered field,
\begin{align}
 a\cdot a^{-1}&=1<0 \\
&\Downarrow\\
 a\cdot a^{-1}\cdot a&<0\cdot a \\
&\Downarrow\\
 a&<0
\end{align}
A contradiction, since by the trichotomy axiom, we cannot have $ a>0 $ and $ a<0
$. Thus we must have that $ 1>0 $.

Comment: If $ a >0$ then it is false that $a\cdot a^{-1}<0$.

Comment: @john Yes, but he assumes $1<0$ and $a\cdot a^{-1}=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Let x $\in$ R and $ x>0 $.
Now, $x.1 = x >0 $ $\implies$ $ x^{-1}.x.1 >x^{-1}. 0 $ $\implies 1>0 $ [$\because a.0 = 0 $ $ \forall $a $\in $ R $]$

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers are not complete.

Axioms of ordered set give us only $\forall x \le 0 \ y \le 0 \ \ \ \ xy \ge 0$.
And we can get only $0 \le 1$.

Now we need to proof the $0 \ne 1$.

$x = x \cdot 1 = x \cdot (1 + 0) = x \cdot 1 + x \cdot 0 \rightarrow x \cdot 0 = 0$

Suppose that $0 = 1$. By the axiom $\forall x \in \mathbb{F} \ \ \ \ x \cdot 1 = x $. But $x \cdot 0 = 0$ by above. Contradiction.

$0 \ne 1 \\ 0 < 1$

QED

Comment: This is not a true contradiction, in fact you showed that all terms in the field are zero since if we suppose $1=0$ then $ x = x \cdot 1 = x \cdot 0 = 0 $, which is the trivial field $\mathbb{F} = \{0\} $. To fix it we might say , suppose we are not in the trivial field, and thus there exists $x \neq 0 $, then your proof follows and we derive a contradiction. But the only way to show we are not in a trivial field is to assume $0 \neq 1 $, which is what we want to prove. This circularity cannot be avoided. Thus it is taken as a field axiom that $ 0 \neq 1 $ it is not necessary to prove it.

Comment: See (also) [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437123/prove-axiomatically-that-1-does-not-equal-0/1663445]

Comment: @john "The trivial field" is not a field. By definition, a field contains more than one element, since $(F\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ is a group (in particular, non-empty).

Answer (score 1):

It is not provable that $0$ unequals $1$. It is part of the field-axioms.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $0 \ge 1$ and let $x > 0$. We have:
$$0 \ge 1$$
$$0 \cdot x \ge 1 \cdot x$$
$$0 \ge x$$ A contradiction with our assumption that  $x > 0$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using that
$$ x \neq 0 \Rightarrow x^2 > 0 $$
leads to
$$ 1^2 > 0 $$
and thereby
$$ 1 > 0 $$