# How to show that $1>0$

Tags: real-analysis

Hello to everyone i just started to proofs in math, and i need a little help in this question

Show that $1>0$ by using ( Algebraic Prooerties of the real numbers) Such as ( Commutativity of Addition & Associativity of Addition & Existence of Additive Identity etc)

Comment: what is AC-AA-AID?

Comment: @RSerrao Such as ( Commutativity of Addition & Associativity of Addition & Existence of Additive Identity etc)

Comment: How do you define $>$?

Comment: You need to tell us _exactly_ what the properties you have are, with no "etc" to hid the interesting parts. Do you have properties for $>$ too, or is it a defined concept for you?

Comment: No sir, i dont have properties of >. I only have (Commutativity of Addition & Associativity of Addition & Existence of Additive Identity & Existence of ADditive Inverses & Commutativity of Multiplication & Associativity of Multiplication & Existence of Multilipcative Identity & Existence Of Multiplicative Inverses And Distributivity)

Comment: If it was negative it would have a negative sign on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I prove that $1 &gt; 0$ in an ordered field?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231438/how-do-i-prove-that-1-0-in-an-ordered-field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sketch of the proof*.

We need some preliminary results :

> **Lemma 0** : $0 \cdot a = 0 = a \cdot 0$.

By the *identity law for addition* ($x+0 = x$) we have : $0+0 = 0$, and so $a(0+
0) = a \cdot 0$. By the *distributive law* : $a \cdot 0+a \cdot 0 = a \cdot 0$, and by *identity law for addition* we have : $a \cdot 0+a \cdot 0 = 0+a \cdot 0$.

Then, by the *cancellation law for addition* : $a \cdot 0=0$. The *commutative law for multiplication* finally implies that : $0 \cdot a = 0$.

> **Lemma 1** : $(-a)b=-ab=a(-b)$.

We prove it using : $(-1) \cdot a = -a$.

In turn, this is proved as follows : $a+a(-1)=a \cdot 1+ a(-1)= a[1+(-1)] = a \cdot 0 = 0$.

> **Lemma 2** : $-(-a)=a$.
>
> **Lemma 3** : If $a \ne 0$, then $a^2 > 0$.

Suppose $a \ne 0$; by *trichotomy* : $a > 0$ or $a < 0$.

*(i)* Suppose that $a > 0$. Then by the *multiplication law for order* (if $x < y$ and $z > 0$, then $xz < yz$), we have that : $a \cdot a > 0 \cdot a$. Then, by **L.0** : $a^2 > 0$.

*(ii)* Suppose that $a < 0$. We have $-a > 0$, and thus (by *(i)*) : $(-a)^2 > 0$. Applying **L.1** twice we have : $(-a)^2 = (-a)(-a) = -[a(-a)] = -[-a^2]$, and thus by **L.2** : $(-a)^2 = a^2$. It follows that $a^2 > 0$.

Now for te main result :

> $1 \ne 0$ (*non-triviality axiom*) and thus by **L.3** : $1 \cdot 1 > 0$.

Applying the *identity law for multiplication* : $x \cdot 1 = x$, we finally have :

> > $1 > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

We assume that $\mathbb{R}$ is a totally ordered field $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,\leq)$. We define $x < y$ to be "$x \leq y$ and $x \neq y$".
I will assume the following properties:

$\quad$(TO1)$\quad$ For any $x$ and $y$, either $x \leq y$ or $y \leq x$ (or both).

$\quad$(TO2)$\quad$ ($x \leq y$ and $y \leq z$) $\implies$ $x+z \leq y + z$.

$\quad$(TO3)$\quad$ ($x \leq y$ and $0 \leq z$) $\implies$ $xz \leq yz$.

$\quad$(F1)$\quad$ For any $x$ we have that $1 \cdot x = x$.

$\quad$(F2)$\quad$ For any $x$ we have that $0 \cdot x = 0$.

$\quad$(F3)$\quad$ For any $x$ we have that $0 + x = x$.

$\quad$(F4)$\quad$ $0 \neq 1$.

$\quad$(F5)$\quad$ $1$ has an additive inverse, $-1$, i.e. $1 + (-1) = 0$.

Assume that $0 \not< 1$. From (F4) we know that $0 \neq 1$, hence $0 \not\leq 1$. Then from (TO1) we have that $1 \leq 0$. Again, since $1 \neq 0$, we now know that $1 < 0$.

Because our field is totally ordered, we have
$$1 < 0 \implies 1 + (-1) < 0 + (-1) \implies 0 < -1,\tag{1}$$
where I used (TO2) in the first step, and (F5) and (F3) in the second step.

But since $0 < -1$, we also have that
$$ 1 < 0 \implies 1 \cdot (-1) < 0 \cdot (-1) \implies -1 < 0,\tag{2}$$
where I used (TO3) in the first step, and (F1) and (F2) in the second step.

Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ together pose a contradiction.

**Note:** Properties (F2) and (F4) you may still have to prove yourself.